# Connect html with USB Device

Tags: html, usb, connect

Is it possible to connect USB device in the HTML page? If yes then How I can? I want to integrate Boogie Board into a dynamic page with a question.

Answer (score 0):

As Boogie Board SDK i.e. Chrome extension provides to draw canvas images using Polymer which is pure js.